# solve for $x$: $\frac{e^{x/80} - 1}{e^{x/4} - 1} = \epsilon$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, perturbation-theory

I am working on a scaling problem in biology. I came across the following equation:

$$\frac{e^{x/80} - 1}{e^{x/4} - 1} = \epsilon.$$

According to wolfram, left-hand side does not have a root, but [the function seems to become arbitrarily small](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28-1%20%2B%20exp%28x%2F80%29%29%20%2F%20%28-1%20%2B%20exp%28x%2F4%29%29%20from%20x%20%3D%200%20to%20300). I was wondering if there is some standard way that, given any $\epsilon > 0$, I can find some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that this equation is true.

Comment: Sure, L'Hospital's rule will suffice to show the result. Solving for $x$ is another matter though.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question so that I wish to find such an $x$ instead of showing the limit becomes 0.

Comment: [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+real+x+in+%28e%5E%28x%2F80%29-1%29%2F%28e%5E%28x%2F4%29-1%29+%3D+y) gives an expression in terms of Root objects, so it seems that there is no closed form.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response. I guess I have more work to do with my problem.

Comment: BTW, you cannot solve it for *every* $\epsilon > 0$: the range of the function is from 1 at $-\infty$ to 0 at $+\infty$ and it's monotonic, so there are no solutions if $\epsilon > 1$. It also becomes very flat for large $|x|$, so numerical solutions are going to be problematic if $\epsilon$ is close to either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is about finding an approximation to the root, we can construct the Puiseux series solution for $u - 1 = \epsilon (u^{20} - 1)$. The first-order approximation comes from $u = \epsilon u^{20}$, giving
$$x \sim -\frac {80} {19} \ln \epsilon, \quad \epsilon \to 0^+.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the limit, equaling the expression of the function to an arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$ isn't the way to do so. But, simply enough it can be found by using L'Hospital's rule, as stated in the comments by Ian :

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x/80} - 1}{e^{x/4} - 1} \stackrel{\frac{\infty}{\infty} D.L.H.}{=} \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{80}e^{x/80}}{\frac{1}{4}e^{x/4}} = 0 $$

Now, for showing that there exists an $x \in \mathbb R^+$ such that the equation is fullfilled, one may proceed by calculus theorems and manipulations of by numerical methods. The exact computation of it is rather complex by hand.

To answer to your comment, the $x$ for which the limit becomes zero "is" $\infty$. This is exactly what we observe in the graph, as it asymptotically reaches zero.